# Puppet how to access files in /etc/puppetlabs/code

Tags: puppet, r10k

I have some files I want to make accessible to all my R10K branches.

I put them in the folder which contains my `environments` folder at `/etc/puppetlabs/code`:

```
-/etc/puppetlabs/code
  - environments/
  - modules/
  - files/
    - file
```

I'm trying to access it from inside an environment like this:

```
$file = file('puppet:///files/file')
```

But I'm getting back a message that it can't be found:

```
Error while evaluating a Function Call, Could not find any files from puppet:///..
```

**Update:**

Also tried moving folder to a new `files` module and adding this to my `Puppetfile`:

```
mod "files", local: true
```

Then referencing the file like:

```
file('puppet:///modules/files/file')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your files in a directory called `files` in your module and reference with `file('puppet:///modules/files/nameoffile')`

Where files is the name of your module and puppet with look for files in `files/files`